# How to pass an input to component which is a part of UI chassis

Tags: angular, primeng

This time stackblitz is not possible. I'll explain here. I'm trying to build a UI chassis of my own in Angular 6. My plan is to pull some common components from `primeng 6` and after applying some CSS of my own I'll build my UI chassis which other people can use. Right now I'm stuck with basic `Datepicker` and it's `locale`.

My chassis code:

**my-datepicker.component.html**

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" name="test" [locale]="localeLang"></p-calendar>
```

**my-datepicker.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-datepicker',
  templateUrl: './my-datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-datepicker.component.scss']
})
export class MyDatepickerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() localeLang: string;

  value;
  
  // spanish
  es = {
    firstDayOfWeek: 1,
    dayNames: ['domingo', 'lunes', 'martes', 'miércoles', 'jueves',...
  };

  // arabic
  arabic = {
    firstDayOfWeek: 1,
    dayNames: ["يوم الأحد‎","يوم الإثنين‎","يوم الثلاثاء‎"...
  };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
  }
}
```

**Note: selector: 'lib-datepicker'**

I am able to `ng build` and `npm publish` successully. Now the problem is, when i use the same component from UI chassis in another Angular 6 project:

**app.component.html**

```
<lib-datepicker [localeLang]="'arabic'"></lib-datepicker>
```

Then it's not working. The datepicker is itself not showing up. However If I hard code the `[locale]=arabic` n UI chassis then it works.

Please point out my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the component isnt initialized and the input value is undefined. Do you have any error messages?

This can also be verified by adding a ngOnChanges hook and log the input value there

like:

```
ngOnChanges() { 
    console.log(this.localeLang);
}
```

Because the OnChanges hook will fire on every change to input-value you will be able to se what the value holds during initiation of the app.

And you could try changing the input to set the value when its ready, like following:

```
currentLocale: string;
@Input() set localeLang(value: string) {
             if(value) {
                 this.locale = value
             }
          }
```

So you add a variable called currentLocale that you set to the value of input when the value is truthy, i. not undefined or null. In this example you will need to add a variable called currentLocale (or any other name you choose) and set that to the value from the input, so you use currentLocale instead of localeLang.

Hopefully this makes sense and will help you.